# generate a VHDL process with clock signal at a frequency of 10mhz

Tags: vhdl

Im struggling to see how my lecturer got 100nanosecs a clock period(50nanosecs up, 50nanosecs down)

the clocks at 10mhz so I did:
          1/ 10x10^6 => 1x10^-7 microSeconds

convert to nano seconds and i got 1x10^-4 nano seconds.

thats not 100nano seconds so where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly 10mhz is milli hertz so capitalize the m and the h to get 10MHz. You know 1MHz has a period of 1 micro second and 1 micro second is 1000 nano seconds. This can only mean that a 10MHz clock has a period of 100 nano seconds.

You should have divided by a thousand and not multiplied by 1000. Also 1 x 10^-7 is not in micro seconds, it is in seconds.

Comment: Perfect example of why capitalization *matters*.